# 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_app_data' in scrapy\twisted\openssl

Tags: python, openssl, scrapy, twisted, pyopenssl

During the scraping process using scrapy one error appears in my logs from time to time.
It doesnt seem to be anywhere in my code, and looks like it something inside twisted\openssl.
Any ideas what caused this and how to get rid of it?

Stacktrace here:

```
[Launcher,27487/stderr] Error during info_callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/webapps/link_crawler/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 415, in dataReceived
        self._write(bytes)
      File "/opt/webapps/link_crawler/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 554, in _write
        sent = self._tlsConnection.send(toSend)
      File "/opt/webapps/link_crawler/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1270, in send
        result = _lib.SSL_write(self._ssl, buf, len(buf))
      File "/opt/webapps/link_crawler/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 926, in wrapper
        callback(Connection._reverse_mapping[ssl], where, return_code)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/opt/webapps/link_crawler/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1055, in infoCallback
        return wrapped(connection, where, ret)
      File "/opt/webapps/link_crawler/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1157, in _identityVerifyingInfoCallback
        transport = connection.get_app_data()
      File "/opt/webapps/link_crawler/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1589, in get_app_data
        return self._app_data
      File "/opt/webapps/link_crawler/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1148, in __getattr__
        return getattr(self._socket, name)
    exceptions.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_app_data'
```

Comment: Don't put part of your question on another site.  Put the stack trace into your question inline.

Comment: A minimal example that reproduces the problem would be useful as well: http://sscce.org/

Comment: ok, i updated the question with stacktrace inline.but i dont have reproducible example because it happens from time to time. maybe like few times for 100k crawled pages, or maybe even less. Its not something that can be  reproduced easily, and all the stacktrace withint the code of libraries not mine code, so have no idea how to make a minimal example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first glance, it appears as though this is due to a bug in scrapy.  Scrapy defines its own Twisted "context factory": https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/ad36de4e6278cf635509a1ade30cca9a506da682/scrapy/core/downloader/contextfactory.py#L21-L28

This code instantiates `ClientTLSOptions` with the context it intends to return.  A side-effect of instantiating this class is that an "info callback" is installed on the context factory.  The info callback requires that the Twisted TLS implementation has been set as "app data" on the connection.  However, since nothing ever uses the `ClientTLSOptions` instance (it is discarded immediately), the app data is never set.

When the info callback comes back around to get the Twisted TLS implementation (necessary to do part of its job) it instead finds there is no app data and fails with the exception you've reported.

The side-effect of `ClientTLSOptions` is a little bit unpleasant but I think this is clearly a scrapy bug caused by mis-use/abuse of `ClientTLSOptions`.  I don't think this code could ever have been very well tested since this error will happen every single time a certificate fails to verify.

I suggest reporting the bug to Scrapy.  Hopefully they can fix their use of `ClientTLSOptions` and eliminate this error for you.

Answer (score 21):

I was able to solve this problem by installing the `service_identity` package:

`pip install service_identity`

Comment: Solved the issue. Thank you.

Comment: What is this witchcraft! Same bug, fixed it straight away. Thanks

Comment: doesnt change a thing for me

Comment: Strange enough. Solved the issue for me, too.

Comment: That didn't work for me at first, but by forcing uninstall that worked ! So just do `pip uninstall service_identity && pip install service_identity`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by replacing https:// with http:// in all image links before sending them to the imagepipeline