# Scrapy script not working to extract events from eventbrite.com

Tags: scrapy, eventbrite

I wrote a spider class to crawl through eventbrite.com and get data about events in the Urbana Champaign area. However I got this error. Can you tell me what's the error? I am new to scrapy so am posting this over here. Can you also tell me how to correct this error?

```
scrapy crawl eventbrite
2015-07-02 17:08:38 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.1 started (bot: tutorial)
2015-07-02 17:08:38 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-07-02 17:08:38 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial'}
2015-07-02 17:08:38 [py.warnings] WARNING: :0: UserWarning: You do not have a working installation of the service_identity module: 'No module named service_identity'.  Please install it from <https://pypi.python.org/pypi/service_identity> and make sure all of its dependencies are satisfied.  Without the service_identity module and a recent enough pyOpenSSL to support it, Twisted can perform only rudimentary TLS client hostname verification.  Many valid certificate/hostname mappings may be rejected.

2015-07-02 17:08:38 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-07-02 17:08:38 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-07-02 17:08:38 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-07-02 17:08:38 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2015-07-02 17:08:38 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-07-02 17:08:38 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-07-02 17:08:38 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
Error during info_callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 415, in dataReceived
    self._write(bytes)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 554, in _write
    sent = self._tlsConnection.send(toSend)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1270, in send
    result = _lib.SSL_write(self._ssl, buf, len(buf))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 926, in wrapper
    callback(Connection._reverse_mapping[ssl], where, return_code)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1055, in infoCallback
    return wrapped(connection, where, ret)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1157, in _identityVerifyingInfoCallback
    transport = connection.get_app_data()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1589, in get_app_data
    return self._app_data
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1148, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._socket, name)
exceptions.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_app_data'

2015-07-02 17:08:49 [twisted] CRITICAL: Error during info_callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 415, in dataReceived
    self._write(bytes)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 554, in _write
    sent = self._tlsConnection.send(toSend)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1270, in send
    result = _lib.SSL_write(self._ssl, buf, len(buf))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 926, in wrapper
    callback(Connection._reverse_mapping[ssl], where, return_code)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1055, in infoCallback
    return wrapped(connection, where, ret)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1157, in _identityVerifyingInfoCallback
    transport = connection.get_app_data()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1589, in get_app_data
    return self._app_data
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1148, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._socket, name)
exceptions.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_app_data'

From cffi callback <function infoCallback at 0x106e78a28>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 926, in wrapper
    callback(Connection._reverse_mapping[ssl], where, return_code)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1059, in infoCallback
    connection.get_app_data().failVerification(f)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1589, in get_app_data
    return self._app_data
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1148, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._socket, name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_app_data'
Error during info_callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 415, in dataReceived
    self._write(bytes)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 554, in _write
    sent = self._tlsConnection.send(toSend)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1270, in send
    result = _lib.SSL_write(self._ssl, buf, len(buf))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 926, in wrapper
    callback(Connection._reverse_mapping[ssl], where, return_code)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1055, in infoCallback
    return wrapped(connection, where, ret)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1157, in _identityVerifyingInfoCallback
    transport = connection.get_app_data()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1589, in get_app_data
    return self._app_data
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1148, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._socket, name)
exceptions.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_app_data'

2015-07-02 17:08:49 [twisted] CRITICAL: Error during info_callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 415, in dataReceived
    self._write(bytes)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 554, in _write
    sent = self._tlsConnection.send(toSend)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1270, in send
    result = _lib.SSL_write(self._ssl, buf, len(buf))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 926, in wrapper
    callback(Connection._reverse_mapping[ssl], where, return_code)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1055, in infoCallback
    return wrapped(connection, where, ret)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1157, in _identityVerifyingInfoCallback
    transport = connection.get_app_data()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1589, in get_app_data
    return self._app_data
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1148, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._socket, name)
exceptions.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_app_data'

From cffi callback <function infoCallback at 0x103b1c9b0>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 926, in wrapper
    callback(Connection._reverse_mapping[ssl], where, return_code)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1059, in infoCallback
    connection.get_app_data().failVerification(f)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1589, in get_app_data
    return self._app_data
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1148, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._socket, name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_app_data'
2015-07-02 17:08:51 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.eventbrite.com/d/il--urbana/events/?crt=regular&sort=date> (referer: None)
2015-07-02 17:08:51 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.eventbrite.com/d/il--champaign/events/?crt=regular&sort=date> (referer: None)
2015-07-02 17:08:51 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-07-02 17:08:51 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 519,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 55279,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 2, 11, 38, 51, 775192),
 'log_count/CRITICAL': 2,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 2, 11, 38, 38, 972701)}
2015-07-02 17:08:51 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30203408/3941341

Your stacktrace seems to be very similar to those in the other question.

And the Scrapy-bug is still open: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1227