# Scrapy spider results can't be pipelined into database when ran from a script

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, web-scraping, scrapy

I've written a Scrapy spider that I am trying to run from a python script located in another directory. The code I'm using from the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html) seems to run the spider, but when I check the postgresql table, it hasn't been created. The spider only properly pipelines the scraped data if I use the *scrapy crawl* command. I've tried placing the script in the directory right above the scrapy project and also in the same directory as the config file and neither seem to be creating the table.

The code for the script is below followed by the code for the spider. I think the problem involves the directory in which the script should be place and/or the code that I use within the spider file to enable the spider to be ran from a script, but I'm not sure. Does it look like there is a problem with the function that is being called in the script or is there something that needs to be changed within the settings file? I can provide the code for the pipelines file if necessary, thanks.

**Script file (only 3 lines)**

```
from ticket_city_scraper import *
from ticket_city_scraper.spiders import tc_spider 

tc_spider.spiderCrawl()
```

**Spider file**

```
import scrapy
import re
import json
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider , Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import Join, MapCompose
from ticket_city_scraper.items import ComparatorItem
from urlparse import urljoin

from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging



bandname = raw_input("Enter bandname\n")
tc_url = "https://www.ticketcity.com/concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets.html"  

class MySpider3(CrawlSpider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [416]
    name = 'comparator'
    allowed_domains = ["www.ticketcity.com"]

    start_urls = [tc_url]
    tickets_list_xpath = './/div[@class = "vevent"]'
    def create_link(self, bandname):
        tc_url = "https://www.ticketcity.com/concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets.html"  
        self.start_urls = [tc_url]
        #return tc_url      

    tickets_list_xpath = './/div[@class = "vevent"]'

    def parse_json(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        ticket_info = jsonresponse.get('B')
        price_list = [i.get('P') for i in ticket_info]
        if len(price_list) > 0:
            str_Price = str(price_list[0])
            ticketPrice = unicode(str_Price, "utf-8")
            loader.add_value('ticketPrice', ticketPrice)
        else:
            ticketPrice = unicode("sold out", "utf-8")
            loader.add_value('ticketPrice', ticketPrice)
        return loader.load_item()

    def parse_price(self, response):
        print "parse price function entered \n"
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        event_City = response.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="addressLocality"]/text()').extract() 
        eventCity = ''.join(event_City) 
        loader.add_value('eventCity' , eventCity)
        event_State = response.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="addressRegion"]/text()').extract() 
        eventState = ''.join(event_State) 
        loader.add_value('eventState' , eventState) 
        event_Date = response.xpath('.//span[@class="event_datetime"]/text()').extract() 
        eventDate = ''.join(event_Date)  
        loader.add_value('eventDate' , eventDate)    
        ticketsLink = loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
        json_id_list= re.findall(r"(\d+)[^-]*$", ticketsLink)
        json_id=  "".join(json_id_list)
        json_url = "https://www.ticketcity.com/Catalog/public/v1/events/" + json_id + "/ticketblocks?P=0,99999999&q=0&per_page=250&page=1&sort=p.asc&f.t=s&_=1436642392938"
        yield scrapy.Request(json_url, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_json, dont_filter = True) 

    def parse(self, response):
        """
        # """
        selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        # iterate over tickets
        for ticket in selector.select(self.tickets_list_xpath):
            loader = XPathItemLoader(ComparatorItem(), selector=ticket)
            # define loader
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()
            # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader
            loader.add_xpath('eventName' , './/span[@class="summary listingEventName"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('eventLocation' , './/div[@class="divVenue location"]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('ticketsLink' , './/a[@class="divEventDetails url"]/@href')
            #loader.add_xpath('eventDateTime' , '//div[@id="divEventDate"]/@title') #datetime type
            #loader.add_xpath('eventTime' , './/*[@class = "productionsTime"]/text()')

            print "Here is ticket link \n" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            #sel.xpath("//span[@id='PractitionerDetails1_Label4']/text()").extract()
            ticketsURL = "https://www.ticketcity.com/" + loader.get_output_value("ticketsLink")
            ticketsURL = urljoin(response.url, ticketsURL)
            yield scrapy.Request(ticketsURL, meta={'loader': loader}, callback = self.parse_price, dont_filter = True)

def spiderCrawl():
   process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
   })
   process.crawl(MySpider3)
   process.start()
```

Comment: Without much investigation (hence the comment), when I saw this kind of error I found [this post's advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202669/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-app-data-in-scrapy-twisted-openssl) helpful.

Comment: @Muttonchop So I looked at that post and found an answer that suggested making this installation: pip install service_identity -- and the error went away. I actually don't think this was the problem since the results still aren't being pipelined into the database so I will revise the post, thanks for the link.

Comment: In your updated post, I don't see you importing `CrawlerProcess`. Did you leave out some imports in the sample code?

Comment: @Muttonchop Yeah, I left out some of the imports. I just updated it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your settings object only contains a user agent. Your project settings are what determine which pipeline gets ran. From scrapy docs:

> You can
>   automatically import your spiders passing their name to
>   CrawlerProcess, and use get_project_settings to get a Settings
>   instance with your project settings.

more info here http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html

Read more than the first example.

Answer (score -1):

The settings are not beeing read if you run from a parent folder.
This answer helped me:
[Getting scrapy project settings when script is outside of root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662797/getting-scrapy-project-settings-when-script-is-outside-of-root-directory)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation). If not, *tailor the answer to this specific question*.